# Div with auto height doesn't resize when elements appended

Tags: php, javascript, css

On this div where the height is specified with CSS to be auto, the div height only changes if the elements contained are shown with display block.  If display is not specified for the contained elements, the div isn't resized.  The elements are added in code with javascript.

Here is the CSS for the div and for the elements appended.

```
    #page {
       height: auto;
       min-height: 83%;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .linkcard, .linkcard_init { 
       position: absolute;
       padding: 0;
       margin-top: 20px;
       margin-left: 20px;
       border: 1px solid DarkKhaki;
       border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
       box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px DarkKhaki;
       z-index: 26;
    }
```

Here is the HTML.  The elements are added to the div container with this code `$("#page").append(response);`.  This appends echo statements from a PHP script.

```
  <div id="page"> <!-- Begin page div -->
    <div id="buttons">  
      <a href="#" onclick="create_linkcard();"> Add LinkCard</a> <br/>
    </div> <!-- End buttons -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
               // Make ajax call to recreate linkcards from XML data
               $.ajax({
                   url: "get_nodes.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: { },
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (response) {

                     if (response != '') 
                     {
                       $("#page").append(response);   /*** ADDING DIV ELEMENTS ***/              
                     }
                   }
               });
    });

    </script>

  </div> <!-- End page div -->
```

The PHP script echoes the response that is appended to the div with code like this.

```
echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'linkcard ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."px; left: ".$node->LEFT."px; width: ".$node->WIDTH."px; height: ".$node->HEIGHT."px;'> \n";

echo "   <p class = 'linkcard_header editableText'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

echo "</div> \n";
```

The elements appear to be floating on top of the div (#page).  They don't seem appended to the div.  I say this because, when I add more elements to #page they are placed under the contained elements at the top left of #page.  What in the code above could explain that the elements float on top instead of being added to the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the height to change based on the content, you need to remove `position:absolute` from the appended element.

Answer (score 0):

They are `position: absolute;`, that's your problem, have them position relative or remove the absolute all together.

Absolute position means that it isn't effected by any elements less a parent absolutely positioned element. With that, the inverse is true, elements without absolute position are not effected by absolutely positioned elements.

Try setting the parent to `position:relative;`, and making the parent `display:block;`

Comment: `position: absolute;` or `position: inherit;` are the only options that allow me to place the elements where I want them on the page.  With that how do I get the elements to be part of the container div `#page` for that div to resize?

Comment: They need to be positioned relative to the parent div, have the parent div be positioned absolute. Otherwise, simulate the expansion with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overflow: hidden` on `#page` may well do the trick. It certainly works to extend the enclosing div when all its contents are floated.

As the others have said, it wouldn't hurt to set `position: relative` on page too. This will ensure that the absolute positions are relative to the `#page` div, rather than the actual page.